# swift: scroll collectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have `collectionView` and I want to scroll to next section on button click. How to do that?

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 4  
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

@IBAction func nextAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //scroll to next
    }
```

**Update**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        cellOffset = 10

        cellWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / 3)  - (cellOffset * 4)
        cellHeight = (cellWidth / 2 * 3) + (cellWidth / 2 * 0.65)

        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in some simple steps:

- find the section number of the first of the currently visible sections
- if the section number is not the last section, add 1 to it
- scroll to the section with the new section number

  ```
  let currentlyVisibleSection = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.map { $0.section }.min()!
  if currentlyVisibleSection < 3 {
      let scrollToSection = currentlyVisibleSection + 1
      collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: scrollToSection), at: .top, animated: true)

  }
  ```

Comment: doesn't work... I change `( item: 0, section: scrollToSection)`

Comment: @111 Oops! `item` should indeed go first. Can you describe how it does not work?

Comment: Nothing happens Nothing scrolling

Comment: @111 Are you sure that some sections are not visible when you press the button? What layout are you using? And I made an edit before to change `indexPathsForVisibleItems.first!.section` to `.indexPathsForVisibleItems.map { $0.section }.min()!` Did you use the version of the code before the edit?

Comment: I change `indexPathsForVisibleItems.map { $0.section }.min()!` to `indexPathsForVisibleItems.first!.section`... nothing changes. I add code to question.

Comment: If I need to add more code in question, tell me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a variable that keep track of currently scrolled section.

```
@IBAction func nextAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let attr = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: currentSection))
    collectionView.setContentOffset(attr!.frame.origin, animated: true)
    currentSection += 1;
    if currentSection >= maxSectionCount {
        currentSection = maxSectionCount - 1
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use this code my `collectionView` scroll right in next section. But also `collectionView` scroll on top about `100`. How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

```
func goToNextSection() {
    guard let nextIndex = getNextSectionIndex() else {
        return
    }
    goToItemAt(nextIndex)
}

func getNextSectionIndex() -> IndexPath? {
    guard let firstVisibleCell = mycollection.visibleCells.first, // maybe last in your scenario
        let indexOfFirstCell = mycollection.indexPath(for: firstVisibleCell) else {
        return nil
    }
    let nextIndex = IndexPath(item: 0, section: indexOfFirstCell.section + 1)
    let yesIhaveCellsHere = true // you need to check if your DS has 'cells' for this, otherwise it will crash at scroll to item
    guard yesIhaveCellsHere else {
        return nil
    }
    return nextIndex
}

func goToItemAt(_ index: IndexPath) {
    mycollection.scrollToItem(at: index,
                              at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.left, // adjust for your scenario
                              animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Does not scroll to the next section. Scrolling about the size of one of the cells.

Comment: ok, sorry I expected cell not section. updating the answer new.

Comment: Doesn't work for me... I have horizontal collectionView. I add new code to question.

Comment: Updated the response, please check

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Maybe I need to add more code? Also I get this `1. Condition always evaluates to true`

Comment: `let yesIhaveCellsHere = true;
guard yesIhaveCellsHere else {
        return nil
    }`

You do understand that this never returns `nil`, right?

Comment: Yes, I was recommending a checkup there as you can read the comment right after. Thank you for your concern :))